# Report Viewer cannot render SQL SERVER 2016 ssrs report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I wrote an application that renders an SSRS report from a 2012 report server using the winforms Report Viewer control and there was no problem. The reports were moved to a new 2016 report server and although the report opens without any problems when I access it straight from the server, my application cannot render it anymore and instead I get a

> 403 - Forbidden error

without any further explanations. My application is a winforms application and it is written in C#.

```
    public void ShowReport()
    {
        this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(REPORT_SERVER_URL);
        this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "REPORT_PATH";

        MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport);
        this.BeginInvoke(mi);
    }
```

Comment: which credentials does your application provide to access the reportserver, and is it known by the new reportserver?

Comment: The report servers (old one and new one) use Windows Authentication so Im passing my windows credentials